# Is it safe to upload any user file to an S3 bucket?

Tags: security, amazon-s3, upload

I want to let users upload file to attach them to a form, is it safe for me to let them upload and retrieve any file or should I be wary of XSS or any other possible vulnerability? The files would be available from the amazonaws domain rather than my own.

Answer (score 1):

The secure way to do this would be to use **Pre-signed URLs** to let them upload new files and only download specific files.

Pre-signed URLs are time-limited URLs that allow a specific file to be uploaded/downloaded. Your application will be responsible for generating these URLs for each specific user. (It is just a few lines of code.)

See:

- [Uploading Objects Using Presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)
- [Share an Object with Others - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)